# Pandas Groupby + Agg to List Very Slow

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I have a DataFrame with 200,000 rows, generated by the code below:

```
In [5]: def create_df():
   ...:     df = {}
   ...:     for col_name in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']:
   ...:         df[col_name] = np.tile(list(range(100000)), 2)
   ...:     return pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I am trying to perform some downstream applications which require a groupby then aggregating the groupby rows into lists as follows:

```
In [7]: df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(list)
Out[7]: 
                                      e               f
a     b     c     d                                    
0     0     0     0              [0, 0]          [0, 0]
1     1     1     1              [1, 1]          [1, 1]
2     2     2     2              [2, 2]          [2, 2]
3     3     3     3              [3, 3]          [3, 3]
4     4     4     4              [4, 4]          [4, 4]
...                                 ...             ...
99995 99995 99995 99995  [99995, 99995]  [99995, 99995]
99996 99996 99996 99996  [99996, 99996]  [99996, 99996]
99997 99997 99997 99997  [99997, 99997]  [99997, 99997]
99998 99998 99998 99998  [99998, 99998]  [99998, 99998]
99999 99999 99999 99999  [99999, 99999]  [99999, 99999]
```

However, this operation is far slower than expected (~15 seconds on average), given that the DataFrame is only 200,000 rows:

```
In [8]: %timeit df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(list)
14.7 s ± 1.13 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

By contrast, applying a count to the groupby only takes ~45 milliseconds on average, which indicates that the slowdown appears to only be aggregating by list:

```
In [10]: %timeit df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg('count')
44.7 ms ± 2.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

What could I do here to make the aggregate by list operation faster? Right now it's a real bottleneck in my code.

Comment: Do you really need list? Using them as the content of a DataFrame is not recomended

Comment: Would you be willing to use tuples? `df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(tuple)`? it gives a 2x speedup in my environment

Comment: `df[["a","b"]].values.tolist()` for a quick cast to list. In your current case there is no need to `groupby`.

Comment: @DaniMesejo that gave me a 5x speedup in my usecase, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind if I posted as an answer?

Comment: Yes please go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use tuple instead of list:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(tuple)
```

This gave a *2x* speedup in my environment:

```
df = create_df()
%timeit df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(tuple)
2.38 s ± 52.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(list)
5.41 s ± 28.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())`.

Comment: Nope that was just as slow as the code in the OP :(